# How to calculate two consecutive values in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to loop through an array and calculate each value with next one. The data is like

```
[
  ['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-07-10'], 
  ['rate' => 2000, 'date' => '2017-08-14'],
  ['rate' => 3000, 'date' => '2017-08-18'],
  ['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-07-23'] 
]
```

I have this [edited, following an example from another question in stackoverflow]:

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
  @if ($user->admin_id == $active_user) // filtering users under this admin  

          @foreach ($userbillings as $userbilling)
            @if($userbilling->user_id == $user->id) // filtering users

              <?php 
                  $count = count($userbilling->created_at);
                  $rates[] = $userbilling->rate; 
                  $diff = 0;


                  for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
                   if (isset($rates[$i + 1])) {
                      $thisValue = $rates[$i];
                      $nextValue = $rates[$i + 1];

                      $diff = $nextValue - $thisValue;
                     }
                  }
                  echo $diff;
               ?>

            @endif
          @endforeach

  @endif
@endforeach
```

This gives me result: `1000 2000 3000 1000 3000`

What I want to achieve is to subtract first item from second, second item from third, third item from forth and so on, until it reaches to the last item. For last item, I want to keep the whole number.

I understand that I need to use array and loop here, and I have tried different ways for past 2 weeks, but cannot get even close.

Please suggest me how to make it work, or give me a guideline how I should proceed. I have searched plenty of questions here, but could not find anything right for my problem. If there is any, please suggest me the link.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: basically this is what I want to calculate. the first column is rate and second is date. I want to find difference between first date to second, then second to third and so on. and calculate rate based on the difference
1000 2017-07-14 
3000 2017-08-18 
2000 2017-08-10 
3000 2017-08-15 
1000 2017-08-23

Comment: Columns? Update your question with an example of the data structure and we might be able to help you - otherwise everyone will have to guess.

Comment: Is it something like this? `[['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-07-14'], ['rate' => 3000, 'date' => '2017-08-18'] /* etc. */]`?

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Please put an example calculation and the expected result in the question, not in comments. Also, `{{ $userbilling->rate }}` is not php code. What are you actually doing there?

Comment: I am sorry... you are right. data is like [['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-07-14'], ['rate' => 3000, 'date' => '2017-08-18'] /* etc. */] as you mentioned

Comment: You are doing too much logic in your view, this needs to be in your controller, you should use relations for the users and have a user->billings relation for a start

Comment: @Ahsan did any of the answers help to answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it helps me a lot. Thank you so much. There are plenty more calculations to do here [I am filtering users under admin guard, then filtering rates for each user]. Once I am done, I will post a comment and accept your answer.

Comment: @Ahsan thanks :) and glad to hear it helped! Best of luck with the rest of the project

Comment: You are very welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified your preferred output but assuming that you want to end up with an array result of the calculations for all pairs, plus the last element as-is, this should get you on the right track.

I would also second a comment above - do not do this sort of logic in a view as it belongs in a controller or somewhere like a service. Keep your views as simple as possible.

Not tested so please do so yourself:

```
<?php

$periods = [
    ['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-07-14'],
    ['rate' => 3000, 'date' => '2017-08-18'],
    ['rate' => 2000, 'date' => '2017-08-10'],
    ['rate' => 3000, 'date' => '2017-08-15'],
    ['rate' => 1000, 'date' => '2017-08-23'],
];

$lastPeriod = count($periods) - 1;
$ratesForPeriods = [];

foreach ($periods as $index => $currentPeriod) {
    if ($index === $lastPeriod) {
        $ratesForPeriods[] = $currentPeriod; // add the last as-is
    } else {
        $nextPeriod  = $periods[$index + 1];
        $currentDate = new DateTime($currentPeriod['date']);

        $interval = $currentDate->diff(new DateTime($nextPeriod['date']));

        $ratesForPeriods[] = [
            'from'  => $currentPeriod['date'],
            'to'    => $nextPeriod['date'],
            'rate'  => $currentPeriod['rate'],
            'days'  => $interval->days,
            'total' => $interval->days * $currentPeriod['rate'],
        ];
    }
}

print_r($ratesForPeriods);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2017-07-14
            [to] => 2017-08-18
            [rate] => 1000
            [days] => 35
            [total] => 35000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2017-08-18
            [to] => 2017-08-10
            [rate] => 3000
            [days] => 8
            [total] => 24000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2017-08-10
            [to] => 2017-08-15
            [rate] => 2000
            [days] => 5
            [total] => 10000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2017-08-15
            [to] => 2017-08-23
            [rate] => 3000
            [days] => 8
            [total] => 24000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [rate] => 1000
            [date] => 2017-08-23
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It showed me the right way to fix the issue even if my question was unclear. Also I will follow your suggestion to put logic in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but here is an example that might help you!

use `array_slice()` & `array_sum()`

```
$array = array( "0"=>1,"1"=>1,"2"=>5,"3"=>1,"4"=>1,"7"=>1,"8"=>3,"9"=>1);
$keys = array_keys($array);
$array = array_values($array);

$newArr = array();

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    $newArr[] = array_sum(array_slice($array, 0, $key+1));
}
$newArr = array_combine($keys, $newArr);

print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

Reference:

- [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the next item in foreach loop like following code :

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item)
{
    echo !empty($items[$key+1]) ? ($items[$key+1]->rate - $item->rate) : $itema->rate;
}
```

Comment: thank you. but it does not work because $key is id of row here. but the rows are not sequential as I am filtering result for each user. so instead of using [$key + 1], I am looking for another way to find the next $key. that will fix my problem

Comment: Try `current()` and `next()` functions.

Comment: Thank you. Although it does not work in this particular problem, I think I will need it in future.